# Groovy Script to add a tab at end of text/XML Request SOAPUI

Tags: java, xml, groovy, tabs, soapui

I am sending a request using SOAPUI and need to add a tab/space at the end of the text/XML message so it is accepted by the server and I get the proper response. I need a Groovy script that will simply add a tab to the end of the text/XML request. Thanks

Comment: "I need a Groovy script that will simply add a tab to the end of the text/XML request.". Ok. Then why not try writing one?

Comment: Why do you need the extra tab/space to be accepted by the server in the first place.  Fix that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go as it's said in the comments is to fix your WS to work correctly without the extra tab/space at the end of your request.

Another simple option if you can't fix de WS because it's a third party service, it's simply to add manually a tab in the *testStep* as part of your request.

Anywise since some times is necessary or util to modify the request for some other reason I will show you an example of how to get the *SOAP Request* with a *Groovy* script to manipulate it.  You can do it adding a *Groovy testStep* with the following code:

```
// get the testStep by name
def testStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('Your request name')
// get request content
def originalRequestContent = testStep.getPropertyValue('request')

// perform your modifications...
// in your case simply add a new tab
def newRequestContent = "${originalRequestContent}\t"
// as tab is not showed in the Raw tab of your testStep, 
// to show that this code work as expected I add 
// and unnecessary extra text
newRequestContent += 'it works'

// set the new modified request
testStep.setPropertyValue('request',newRequestContent)
// and finally you can send the request
testStep.run(testRunner,context)
// if you want to keep the step as orignal uncomment
// the follow line
// testStep.setPropertyValue('request',originalRequestContent)
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you so much! It is a third party service so, sadly I couldn't fix the actual service.